# Where is the key _wp_page_template passed?

Tags: pages, metabox, post-meta

When adding custom post meta boxes, I understand that whatever `name` attribute `input` you put would be passed through the form into the server.

Hence, If I have

```
<input type="text" name="my_custom_field" id="my_custom_field" />
```

using

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_custom_field', true);
```

I am able to retrieve the value of that `input` is possible.

Regarding this, I did some googling on how to target custom page templates and this was what I found.

```
global $post;
function func_name {
    if ( 'foobar.php' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true ) ) {
         do something...
     }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_page', 'func_name' );
```

Where does `_wp_page_template` come from?

I did a inspect on the WP backend edit page on the Page Attributes meta box but no  fields have that key name on it. What boggles me is how `_wp_page_template` also appears in the database wp_postmeta table.

Can anyone help me explain this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML attribute `name` is what is sent to the server. There is some PHP code reading it and storing it with a specific key in the database.

The HTML name and the database key don’t have to be the same string. The PHP code can use a completely different name or split one value into multiple database values.

The template attribute handler does that: It takes the name `page_template` from page attributes metabox and stores it as `_wp_page_template` in the database. The leading underscore protects that field from showing up in the *custom fields* metabox.

See this part in `wp_insert_post()`:

```
if ( !empty($page_template) && 'page' == $data['post_type'] ) {
    $post->page_template = $page_template;
    $page_templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates();
    if ( 'default' != $page_template && ! isset( $page_templates[ $page_template ] ) ) {
        if ( $wp_error )
            return new WP_Error('invalid_page_template', __('The page template is invalid.'));
        else
            return 0;
    }
    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_wp_page_template',  $page_template);
}
```

Comment: From what I understand, the $meta_key value of 'update_post_meta' is the new key in which is ultimately saved with the $meta_value, which is $_POST['name_attribute_of_inputetc']. So what is 'name' you call in the 'input' doesn't have to be the same as what is saved. But what advantage is there to store it as a different meta key?

Comment: There is no real advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Saving data from a form is not automatic as you seem to think...

> When adding custom post meta boxes, I understand that whatever name
>   attribute input you put would be passed through the form into the
>   server. Hence, if `<input type="text" name="my_custom_field"
>   id="my_custom_field" />`, using `get_post_meta($post->ID,
>   'my_custom_field', true);` to retrieve the value of that input is
>   possible.

Yes, the form data will be passed to the server as either `POST` or `GET` data but nothing happens to that data if it is not intentionally processed by the script. That often means saving to the database but not necessarily. You can email the data instead, as part of a contact form for example.

The `name` attribute the form uses does not have to match the key saved to the database. The code that processes the form can save it it under any key the programmer wants.

The particular piece of data you are talking about is processed by the `wp_insert_post` function in [`wp-includes/post.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/post.php).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've completely forgotten to mention the saving part after posting the form. That isn't what I'm trying to ask, sorry for the unclarity.